# ng-bootstrap: Use scss in project

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

My angular project is using scss and before I switched to ng-bootstrap I followed this guideline to integrate bootstrap with scss in my angular project: https://shermandigital.com/blog/bootstrap-sass-with-angular-cli/

Now I switched to ng-bootstrap. Is there something similar?

Comment: ng-bootstrap is only a group of widgets. If you have already use bootstrap 4.0.0 your components will work correctly else update your bootstrap with the last version

Comment: no currently it is not working. No bootstrap is applied. What do you need to find the error?

Comment: Sure you use bootstrap 4.0. put in a component < button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" >Primary< /button >. If the button is not  out-line this is the problem

Comment: is bootstrap not installed automatically as a dependency if I'm installing ng-bootstrap?

Comment: NO. Moreover, ng-bootstrap NOT use bootstrap's javascript. Only need bootstrap.css. This is because I told you that if you are using bootstrap with scss you get already it

Comment: I found out that I need an import in main.scss: @import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Answer (score 1):

Net, in a angular project you write

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

In your main module.ts 
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

OR in a module.ts

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [OtherComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule, ...]
})
export class OtherModule {
}
```

then, you can write in a component, e.g.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
```

If you have ALREADY import bootstrap.css.4.0 WHATEVER WAY(*), you can see the tooltip correct, if not you can see a tooltip, but not well formated.

(*) it would simply be worth to import the css in angular-cli.json add

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../bootstrap.css"
      ],
```